# Steady-state adiabatic nozzle, unknown exit velocity & temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, flow, adiabatic, steady-state

The question is 2.10 taken from: Introductory Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics, 2E by Elliot,Lira

> Air at 30ºC and 2MPa flows ata steady state in a horizontal pipeline with a velocity of 25m/s. It passes through a throttle valve where the pressure is reduced to 0.3MPa. The pipe is the same diameter upstream and downstream of the valve. What is the outlet temperature and velocity of the gas? Assume air is an ideal gas with a temperature-independent Cp=7R/2 and the average molecular weight is 28.8.

Since it is to be discribed as a steady state, and that we may assume that $\Delta E_{pot}=0$ since the pipeline is horizontal we end up with
$\dot{m}\left [ \Delta H+\Delta E_{kin} \right ]=0$. Or simply: $$H_{2}-H_{1}+\frac{v_{2}^{2}-v_{1}^{2}}{2g_{c}}=0$$
But since both $T_{2}$ and $v_{2}$ are unknown I do not know how to solve for $H_{2}$.
Therefore I would want to find the exit temperate using the following formula: $ T_{2}=(\frac{P_{2}}{P_{1}})^{(\frac{R}{C_{P}})}T_{1} $ to find the exit temperature. And I also know that the Volume and Velocity are closely related, and important in solving the problem. This since the volume will be higher for the same m when exiting compared to entering the nozzle.

What would be a reasonable approach to this problem, and have I made any assumptions falsely?

Continuation 1:
Through $PV=nRT$ we find that $\frac{V_{1}}{n}=\frac{RT_{1}}{P_{1}}=\frac{8.31446JK^{-1}mol^{-1}*303.15K}{2*10^6MPa}=0.0012602642745\frac{m^3}{n}$

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your notation, but you seem to claim that you don't know T1 when it's outright stated in your problem. P1, T1 are given, so the first specific volume should be easy. The second specific volume should come mass balance, which I think you have not yet written.

Comment: Yes, I had mistakenly written T1 & v1 instead of T2 & v2.

Unfortunately I do not know what you mean by the mass balance apart from my simplified expression $\dot{m}\left [ \Delta H+\Delta E_{kin} \right ]=0$.

Comment: The diameter (and thus flow area) remains the same. Therefore, (rho V A)_1 = (rho V A)_2, which is solvable for V2 (second velocity). Now your energy equation should only have one unknown left. The m_dot in your last equation can be canceled out, but the kinetic energy term still needs V2 it looks like.